# Grep tags for a git repo from gitlab/github

Tags: git, github, tags

I am wondring if it's possible to grep a repo's tags from the github or gitlab without having to clone it, I have a ssh keys to that repo.

For terminal I use this command to list tags for a specific repo I have cloned:

```
git --git-dir=/root/project-test/.git tag
```

This didn't work:

```
git ls-remote git@git.mit.usa.com:s1868/project-test.git --tags
```

Comment: maybe `git ls-remote --tags` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I wasn't able to list the tags tho.

Comment: Actually it worked, but how can I run that command without have to be in that repo? I just want to grep tags from the gitlab without having to clone it in the first place.

Comment: In a cloned repo run `git remote -v show`, then just use the full path that returns in your `ls-remote` call.

Comment: I dont want to clone it, I just want to grep tags from the gitlib/github.

Comment: That was just to get the URL to use.  The syntax you mention as not working should work, post the error output.

Comment: I dont get any error, it just doesn't show any tags.

Comment: Just to be sure, would `git ls-remote --tags git@git.mit.usa.com:s1868/project-test.git` works better?

Answer (score -1):

If you wish just to print them on screen as suggested before: `git ls-remote --tags`

If you want to fetch them to your local repo you simply fetch all:
**`git fetch --all --prune`**. All will fetch all branches and tags, prune will remove the deleted ones.